# setting default path in windows with putty

Tags: windows, putty, user-folders

How do I set a default destination path for Windows using putty? I want to be able to login to a default path on the server (got that), but I want to set a default file transfer path rather than having to navigate through the local drive each time.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to go be able to open a specific folder (directory) in Windows without having to navigate to it manually.

Comment: Are you mixing up Putty and WinSCP? Putty is mainly an SSH client and some scp tools for command-line. File-transfer sounds like you are using WinSCP to me.